# macOS high Sierra 10.13.6(17G12034）にてNvidia web driverを正常に使いたい

Tags: macos, tensorflow, gpu

https://developpaper.com/tensorflow-1-8-with-gpu-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-6/

こちらのサイトを参考に、nvidia web driver をインストールしようと思ったのですが、high sierra 10.13.6(17G12034）に対応しているものが 387.10.10.10.40.135 しかありませんでした。
このバージョンのドライバに対応しているのがCUDA 10.1で、上のサイトで使用されているのがCUDA9.2なので、tensorflowをビルドすることができなくて困っています。

また、CUDAtoolkitなど全てを Nvidia web driver のバージョンに合わせてみても、GPUを認識してくれません。

```
$nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:08:12_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
```

また、

```
$./bin/x86_64/darwin/release/deviceQuery

./bin/x86_64/darwin/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

と表示されます。
上のサイトに書かれていることは全てやりました。
GPUを認識しないのは何故なのでしょうか。
拙い文章で申し訳ありません。回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: TensorFlowの版数が古いからでは？ Macでは無いですがこんな記事があります。[NvidiaドライバとCUDAとcuDNNとTensorflow-gpuとPythonのバージョンの対応](https://qiita.com/konzo_/items/a6f2e8818e5e8fcdb896), [【機械学習】Tensorflow・CUDA・cuDNN環境づくりの手引き](http://dslab.work/2019/09/19/post-224/)

Comment: TensorFlowとMacOSとCUDAの優先順位付けですね。全部を最新(どころかある程度新しくても)は無理で先が無いようですし、公式はもっと古いCUDA8までしかサポートしていないようです。[TensorFlow>インストール>ソースからのビルド](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) `macOS 用の GPU サポートはありません。`およびそのページの一番下, [NVIDIA、macOSをサポートした最後のCUDA Toolkiをv10.2リリース。次期アップデートでmacOSは非サポートに。](https://applech2.com/archives/20191124-nvidia-last-release-to-support-macos-for-cuda.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS{10.13.6（17G12034}になっていますか?
NVIDIA Web Driver:387.10.10.1040.135
CUDA Driver Version: 418.163